# What happens to a platform event if it has no subscribers?

Tags: platform-event

I have a platform event and I have published it using Apex code. Wanted check the behavior if it has no subscribers. Unable to find any info. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens, the event is published as usual. Subscribers may come and go and there may be 0 subscribers at any given point in time.